# ruamel.yaml cannot handle NamedTuple

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

So I have the following piece of code:

```py
import sys
from typing import NamedTuple

import ruamel.yaml as ryaml


class Loc(NamedTuple):
    lat: float
    long: float


data = {
    "APAC": {
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": ["Jane", "John"],
        "locs": [Loc(1.0, 1.0), Loc(2.0, 2.0)],
    },
    "EMEA": {
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": ["Jane", "Jack"],
        "locs": [Loc(3.0, 3.0), Loc(4.0, 4.0)],
    }
}


def main():
    # Just to check that Loc is indeed recognized as a tuple
    assert all(map(lambda o: isinstance(o, tuple), data["APAC"]["locs"]))
    assert all(map(lambda o: isinstance(o, tuple), data["EMEA"]["locs"]))

    yml = ryaml.YAML()
    yml.register_class(Loc)
    yml.dump(data, sys.stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But whenever I execute the code, I ended up with a series of exception ending with:

```
  File "C:\Repos\@Venv\myproj-cpy3.11-1\Lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 1090, in represent_yaml_object
    anchor = state.pop(Anchor.attrib, None)
             ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

If I use 'bare' `tuple` instead of `Loc()`, error doesn't appear.

How do I make `ruamel.yaml` understand that `Loc` is a `NamedTuple` is a `tuple`?

I'm using `CPython 3.11` and `ruamel.yaml==0.17.21`

Comment: It's probably just not recognizing subclasses of `tuple`, probably hardcoded somewhere is `type(node) is tuple` or something like that. Have you considered just using a regular user-defined class (maybe with `__slots__` depending on your motivation for using `NamedTuple`?)

Comment: I suspect that the mechanics behind the class created by the namedtuple class factory is tripping up whatever hueristics ruamel.yaml uses to serialize an arbitrary, user-defined object (so for exampled, your `tuple` class has a bunch of descriptors that wrap access to the tuple positionally instead of regular attributes). Is there no way to define your own serialization when you register the class?

Comment: Just skimming the docs, it seems you can do that by defining `to_yaml` and `from_yaml` classmethods.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well I probably _can_ do that, but the very first example in the documentation shows how a custom class named `User` only needs to be registered without needing any additional methods... here see a snapshot of the doc: https://imgur.com/a/glCIQud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason
you register the `Loc` class, but you don't tell `ruamel.yaml` how to dump that class, and that information is not automatically added, and relatively new features (like `NamedTuple` and e.g. `DataClasses`( are not explicitly recognised and handled in a special way by the ruamel.yaml codebase (if they were, they probably would not even have to be registered for dumping, but they probably would have to be for loading).

The [example](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html) in the documentation shows that that is done for
the registered class, namely by adding a `to_yaml` class method,
so you need to do that for `Loc` as well.

```py
import sys
from typing import NamedTuple
import ruamel.yaml

class Loc(NamedTuple):
    lat: float
    long: float

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_sequence('!Loc', node)
 
data = {
    "APAC": {
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": ["Jane", "John"],
        "locs": [Loc(1.0, 1.0), Loc(2.0, 2.0)],
    },
    "EMEA": {
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": ["Jane", "Jack"],
        "locs": [Loc(3.0, 3.0), Loc(4.0, 4.0)],
    }
}

def main():
    assert all(map(lambda o: isinstance(o, tuple), data["APAC"]["locs"]))
    assert all(map(lambda o: isinstance(o, tuple), data["EMEA"]["locs"]))

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.register_class(Loc)
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

main()
```

which gives:

```
APAC:
  rating: 5
  leads:
  - Jane
  - John
  locs:
  - !Loc
    - 1.0
    - 1.0
  - !Loc
    - 2.0
    - 2.0
EMEA:
  rating: 5
  leads:
  - Jane
  - Jack
  locs:
  - !Loc
    - 3.0
    - 3.0
  - !Loc
    - 4.0
    - 4.0
```

Comment: Well, the very first example, the `User` class didn't have any `to_yaml()` method but it just works. So I naturally thought I can do the same with NamedTuple.

Comment: A thought: I'd understand if dataclasses explicitly require a to_yaml() method, because it has mind-bogglingly many variations. But I think (subclasses of) NamedTuple should be handled natively, as it is just a tuple for all practical purposes.

Comment: `User` is a a normal class and `ruamel.yaml` has some built-in logic to then dump the attributes (IIRC skipping the ones starting with an underscore). Nothing special has been done for named tuples but it could be, and they could posseble even be added to the SafeLoader/Dumper (the default round-trip loader can already load the output, but it will created `CommentedSeq` instances (with tag information)).